# How do you stub external interfaces (e.g., a web service) in AS3 if you can't access/stub private interfaces?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm running into conceptual difficulty in effectively testing an AS3 class that makes web service calls. Take the following example code:

```
class ServiceWrapper extends EventDispatcher
  public function doStuff():void {
    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader;
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
    request.url = 'http://myapiendpoint.com/foo';
    var self:ServiceWrapper = this;
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(event:Event):void {
      if(loader.data == 'success') {
        this.dispatchEvent('stuffDone');
      } else {
        this.dispatchEvent('stuffNotDone');
      }
    });
    loader.load(request);
  }
end
```

I simply want to test that if the service returns 'success' the instance dispatches a `stuffDone` event type and otherwise dispatches a `stuffNotDone`.

It would appear that there's no way to mock the web service response without exposing "test interfaces" in the application code. For example, the following examples come to mind:

- Make the `loader` a public attribute or returned from a public and replace it with a mock in a test.
- Make the `loader` or a function that generates it protected and define a private class that extends `ServiceWrapper` to provide runtime access to or a lasting mock to the `loader`.

The first option modifies the interface in a pretty ugly way. It can be resolved through documentation (or possibly through namespacing; not so sure about how to go about that), and I'm fine if it's the only option, but I feel like there ought to be a better way.

The second one slightly better preserves the interface I suppose but requires a large amount of additional code in the test.

Is there some solution or perspective on the problem I'm overlooking? Thanks in advance for the assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first option should be the way to go: Mock the loader.

It is always advisable not to have object creation code inside reusable classes, unless the created instances remain strictly private and interact only with the class that created them - which is never the case when using an external service.  Instead, pass the loader as a constructor argument - that way, you can be sure it has been created when you call it.

Object creation *should* happen inside your main partition, if not via a dependency injection framework, i.e. the parts of the system which will have to be rewritten for every new app.

There is no need for additional documentation, either: All the documentation you need is in your unit test.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm afraid I can't quite see eye to eye with your point that the involvement of an external service makes the loader instance _not_ private. For example, when I use a Twitter client library, I'm not sure I expect to have to instantiate and pass in a URLLoader to the constructor. From an interface perspective, the loader is "private". All that said, I appreciate the answer for illustrating what appears to be the conventional solution to the problem at this point. Many thanks.

Comment: Well, the thing is: Your variable may be private, but the test won't work without network access, a viable service connection, etc.  In short: You are interacting with the outside world. That's an external dependency, and that is exactly what you don't want to test in a unit test - you want to test the unit's functionality, and only that. That's why you *always* mock everything that uses network or I/O - testing the connection belongs in an integration test, and that, in turn, should not have to worry about your wrapper being functional.